# "No symbols loaded for the current document" while debugging JavaScript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm working on a .NET 3.5 website, with three projects under one solution. I'm using jQuery in this project. I'd like to use the Visual Studio JavaScript debugger to step through my JavaScript code. If I set a breakpoint in any of the .js files I get a warning that says:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

How do I fix this? I'm guessing that Visual Studio is having some trouble parsing through some of the jQuery code. I will try to replace the minimized version of `jQuery.js` with the expanded version, but I don't think that will fix it.

Comment: a little more info might help. the javascript code i want to step through is in an external .js file.

Comment: I have this same identical problem and also do not have an answer.  I voted the question up and I'm looking for an answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was experiencing the same behavior in Visual Studio 2008, and after spending several minutes trying to get the symbols to load I ended up using a workaround - adding a line with the "debugger;" command in my JavaScript file.

After adding `debugger;` when you then reload the script in Internet Explorer it'll let you bring up a new instance of the script debugger, and it'll stop on your debugger command let you debug from there.

In this scenario I was already debugging the JavaScript in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), but I wanted to debug against Internet Explorer as well.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you turn on [script debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx) in your internet options.  And if you think it's on, double check it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, but I solved it by changing my browser settings in Internet Explorer. Go to menu *Tools* -> *Internet Options*, select the *Advanced* tab, then make sure that both "Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)" and "Disable Script Debugging (Other)" are unchecked.

Also, I needed to set Internet Explorer as my default browser, which is normally set as Firefox. To do that, in Visual Studio just right click on any browseable file in [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools) and select "Browse With..." Select Internet Explorer and click "Set as Default".

I'm not sure if there's a way to get debugging running with other browsers, but it wouldn't surprise me if Visual Studio only plays nice with Internet Explorer.

Also, you may need to do "Attach to process" and add `IExplorer.exe` to get the debugger to start.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) for JavaScript debugging. Give it a spin :)

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer to this I think.

When you attach your debugger to the iexplore.exe process, you need to make sure you select "Script" as one of the debugging choices.

It's the button in a red box here: [Screenshot of Select Button in Attach to Process Window](http://screencast.com/t/5uAUb3g9H8)

Then on the next screen, choose Script: [Screenshot of Select Code Type window](http://screencast.com/t/AeWH27rc)

This will warn you that you cannot debug Managed and Script at the same time, but that should be fine because your managed code is your server code and you attach to the web process (aspnet or w3wp) instead.

You'll know you did it right because VS 2008 will load ALL the script documents pertaining to that page (inline stuff, eval stuff, etc.) in Solution Explorer.

You'll have full access to the DOM, the immediate window will work, etc.  It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 3):

One other thing you might look for is a syntax error in your JavaScript code.  That is what happened to me today.  No symbols would load because I had one too many parentheses in my code.  The IntelliSense barely registered the error. Once I fixed the syntax error, everything worked normally.

Answer (score 3):

All of these answers are correct, but there is one more thing to check.  Until yesterday I was always able to debug my JavaScript code from inside of Visual Studio ([2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012)).  I had added a [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) project to the solution, which turned on the Silverlight Debugger. This was my problem.

On the property page for the web application -> Start Options -> at the bottom of the page be sure that "Silverlight" is unchecked. Actually, I have only ASP.NET checked and now the debugger goes through Visual Studio.

Unchecking it and now the debugger stops on the "initialize" function as I wanted.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen - Bored are you?  Editing a posted that is nearly 3 years old.  Awesome - NOT

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the IDE to parse the JavaScript code. Just wait a while and you should see the JavaScript code change color. You will then be able to add breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to update the IE from version 9 to 11. Hope it helps to someone. Peace!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same annoying issues on [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013), and JavaScript development without a debugger is just suicide.

All I did to fix it was to right click the break point red dot -> *Disable Breakpoint* and then right click again -> Enable Breakpoint.

This made the debugger work on JavaScript like a charm again.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have this problem with external JavaScript files - it is caused by the browser cache holding onto an old copy of the file. Forcing a refresh of the page linking to the JavaScript code solves the issue in this case.

Of course, make sure your debugger is attached to the correct browser process. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps glaringly obvious, but I stumbled over this for a second, so perhaps others will too. I didn't have Internet Explorer set up to handle HTML/HTTP, and hence it was not launched when I pressed the run button in Visual Studio.

Instead, I was starting Firefox. I went to **Start Button | Default Programs**, set all the defaults for Internet Explorer, and then debugging started working in Visual Studio for me without any other fuss.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when your solution has multiple web projects, even if they're being served from a different ASP.NET Development Server (WebDev.WebServer40.exe) instance on different ports.

Answer (score 0):

If running two or more web projects within your solution and you have multiple script files with the same name at the same place in different webs, the development web-servers may serve up the wrong file, causing this problem.

In my case, deleting the extra copies resolved the problem.