# The debugger breaks 2 lines below where he should have break

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I work on Visual Studio 2012 with ASP.NET MVC4. Today I placed a breakpoint in my code (see below). At runtime the breakpoint is not hit. So I decided to place the `debugger;` statement in my code to force a break. At runtime, it breaks 2 lines after the `debugger;` statement (see below). Very strange to me. As you can see the yellow box is the same size as the `debugger;` statement.

Any idea?

Thanks.

[image]

**EDIT: below is the screenshot where I hover the breakpoint**

[image]

Comment: looks like code does not match information in pdb files.

Comment: ok so what do I have to do? Thanks.

Comment: The code is moved by the lines you added. I have never debugged js in the VS so I am not 100% sure how this works. When I see this when debugging C# code it means that - if this is my project - I need to rebuild the code so that information in pdb matches the code or - if this is someone else's code - I need to find a version of dll and pdb that matches the code.

Comment: I already rebuild my entire solution. I also deleted bin and obj folders.

Comment: Were you able to figure out why the dubugger originally did not break on the breakpoint - I think it is related. Set the breakpoint and hover over it when running it should say why it is disabled

Comment: I updated my question to show you the 'reason' why the breakpojnt is disabled. Bu so far I have no idea why... I already try things without luck.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115472/no-symbols-loaded-for-the-current-document-while-debugging-javascript-in-visua?

Comment: I have seen this link but not really helpful.